# After hosting asp.net core web api as Window Service, https (https://localhost:5001/api/values) - - not accessible

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I created a brand new asp.net core web api app using default template with `HTTPS` configured.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

[image]

When I run the app as `console` application, then `https` site (https://localhost:5001/api/values) is accessible and gave `API` result.

Now when I deployed this web API as `Window Service`, then site `http` site is accessible, but `https` site (https://localhost:5001/api/values) is not accessible? Whats the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a certificate

> dotnet dev-certs https -ep "localhost.pfx" -p Password1 --trust

I added below code,

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        // Configure the Url and ports to bind to
        // This overrides calls to UseUrls and the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable, but will be 
        // overridden if you call UseIisIntegration() and host behind IIS/IIS Express
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.pfx", "Password1");
            });
        })
```

And it's working even after hosting web api as window service.